# Exec Linux command as user in PHP

Tags: php, linux

I'm converting a document file to html. I've installed LibreOffice on Linux server.

Here's the command,

```
$cmd = "libreoffice4.1 --headless -convert-to html /var/www/html/CV.doc -outdir /var/www/html/";
```

This command is working fine when I execute directly on the Linux server but when I tried to execute it via PHP it will not convert.

```
exec($cmd,$out,$err);
```

The `$err` is printing `127`.

Kindly, let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason for this is that the `$PATH` environment variable hasn't been populated to your PHP application. In this case use the full path to libreoffice:

```
$cmd = "/usr/bin/libreoffice4.1 --headless  ... ";
```

The path `/usr/bin` may differ on your system. Type `which libreoffice4.1` in terminal to find it out.

---

Another reason for the problem might be insufficient permissions to write files into the target directory or read the original documents. In this case make sure that the php application has proper permissions to do so. !`root` permissions **must not** being required for that! This would be a security flaw in your application.

Comment: It's now giving 126 error which means permissions denied. any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Are you using the apache webserver?

Comment: You can issue `sudo chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html/`

Comment: Then the apache group has a different name on your system. Find out what is the apache group name on your system and use this. (probably 'apache' or 'apache2' or 'httpd') You can find it out with `<?php echo system('whoami');`

Comment: it's apache. I've given the permission and still not working :(

Comment: issue: `sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod g+w  {} \;`

Comment: It installs a virus. :) No, it just permits group write permissions to all files below `/var/www/html`.

Answer (score 0):

You say this:

> This command is working fine when I execute directly on the Linux
>   server but when I tried to execute it via PHP it will not convert.

And your command is this:

```
$cmd = "libreoffice4.1 --headless -convert-to html /var/www/html/CV.doc -outdir /var/www/html/";
```

It could be that as a user logged into the system the path to `libreoffice4.1` is part of your default user path. But when Apache (I assume) is running PHP it does not know where the `libreoffice4.1` binary is.

So my solution would be to include the full path to the file in your command like this:

```
$cmd = "/full/path/to/this/binary/libreoffice4.1 --headless -convert-to html /var/www/html/CV.doc -outdir /var/www/html/";
```

Of course replacing `/full/path/to/this/binary/` with the actual path to the file.

You can easily determine the full path to the binary by logging into your sever & typing in the following command:

```
which libreoffice4.1
```

The returned output should be the full path your `libreoffice4.1` binary file. The path should be something like this:

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice4.1
```

Or this:

```
/usr/local/bin/libreoffice4.1
```

But the `which` command on your system will return the full path to the file, so use that output as your guide.